# MongoDB how to get count of comments + replies

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aws-documentdb

So I have this structure in my MongoDB instance.

```
{
  "post_body": "test",
  "author": "test1",
  "comments":[
    {
      "comment_body": "comment test",
      "comment_author": "test2",
      "replies": [
        {
          "reply_body": "reply test1",
          "reply_author": "test3"
        },
        {
          "reply_body": "reply test2",
          "reply_author": "test2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to get the total count of comments + replies.

So my desired output should be

```
{
    "post_body": "test"
    "author": "test1",
    "comment_count": 3
}
```

So far using `$project` only returns the total count of comments only. I want to get the total of comments + replies

Answer (score 1):

```
import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = myclient["test"]
comments_col = db["comments"]
doc = {
    "post_body": "test",
    "author": "test1",
    "comments": [
        {
            "comment_body": "comment test",
            "comment_author": "test2",
            "replies": [
                {
                    "reply_body": "reply test1",
                    "reply_author": "test3"
                },
                {
                    "reply_body": "reply test2",
                    "reply_author": "test2"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}

def insert(doc1):
    id_comment = comments_col.insert(doc1)
    return id_comment
def find(id_comment):
    comment = comments_col.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(str(id_comment))})
    return comment
if __name__ == "__main__":
    id_comment = insert(doc)
    comment = find(id_comment)
    print("comments with replies : ", comment["comments"])
    print("\n")
    print("replies : ", comment["comments"][0]["replies"])
    print("\n")
    print("comment_author : ", comment["comments"][0]["comment_author"])
    print("\n")
    print("comment_body : ", comment["comments"][0]["comment_body"])
```

Comment: Better to use aggregation pipeline, so that it will perform the operation for all the documents in the collection

Answer (score 0):

Using [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) we can get the desired result

Below query uses Pipeline Stages [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and Pipeline operators [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  { $project: {
     "post_body": 1, 
     "author": 1,
     "comments":1,
     "comments_size":{$size: "$comments" }
    }
  }, 
  { $unwind: "$comments" }, 
  { $project: {
     "post_body": 1, 
     "author": 1,
     "comments":1,
     "comments_size":1, 
     "replies_size" : {$size: "$comments.replies"} 
    }
  },
  { $project: {
     "_id":0, 
     "post_body": 1,
     "author": 1,
     "comments_count":{$sum:["$comments_size", "$replies_size"]}
    }
  }
])
```

First part of the aggregation query uses $project and we are just projecting the required attributes to next stage and also we are finding the size of the comments array. The size of the comments array is stored in a temporary attribute `comments_size`

Second part uses $unwind to break the nested array in `comments` and `comments.replies`, the `comments` array is unwinded and `comments.replies` array is kept unaltered

Third part uses $project to find the size of the replies and it is stored in a temporary attribute `replies_size`

Fourth and final part uses $project again with $sum of `comments_size` and `replies_size` to get the desired result